# Overlay background colour scrolls away

Tags: scroll, background-color

I am trying to create an overlay that shows a long message. You can scroll and read it and you can close the overlay.

The overlay has a background colour, but when I scroll the overlay to see the text the background scrolls with it. I want the background colour to stay there until the overlay is hidden.

```
<div id="message-overlay">
      <p>
        Blah blah blah - long message
      </p>
      <button>
        Closes the overlay, this works
      </button>
</div>

#message-overlay {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour to learn how Stack Overflow works and read How to Ask on how to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I just added:

```
overflow: auto;
```

to my overlay CSS and it works now.

Thanks for the support.